Got error when using Spark to read Hive external table
Im using Spark 3.5.0, Hive is 4.0.0.
I already create a table news in hive and stored as Parquet.


+----------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------+-------------+
| news.id  |                     news.link                      |                   news.headline                    |  news.category  |               news.short_description               |  news.authors  |  news.date  |
+----------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------+-------------+
| 5        | https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/7-amazing-name-generators-photos_us_5bacfb45e4b04234e85527ea | 7 Amazing Name Generators (PHOTOS)                 | COMEDY          | Let's be honest: most of our names are pretty boring. Glenn Close? John Mayer? Barack Obama? C'mon, we can do better than | Seena Vali     | 2012-01-28  |
| 4        | https://www.huffingtonpost.comhttp://www.refinery29.com/1-girl-4-looks-lily-kwong | 1 Girl, 4 Looks: Meet NYC's Hottest New Model, Lily Kwong | STYLE & BEAUTY  | From Refinery29: When we tell you Lily Kwong is everything, we're not using the same inflection as when, say, we're talking |                | 2012-01-28  |
| 3        | https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/girl-with-the-dragon-tattoo-india_us_5bb3e3f1e4b066f8d2513c8e | 'Girl With the Dragon Tattoo' India Release Canceled After Local Censor Board Deemed Film 'Unsuitable' | ENTERTAINMENT   | "Sony Pictures will not be releasing The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo in India. The Censor Board has adjudged the film unsuitable |                | 2012-01-28  |
| 2        | https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/dont-think-the-chemical-brothers-concert_us_5bb21e37e4b0171db69d5bf6 | 'Don't Think': A Look At The Chemical Brothers' Concert Film, Set To Hit Theaters | CULTURE & ARTS  | Amid cheers and the occasional "Here we go!" from the theater's speakers, the duo danced alone for a few songs. Eventually | Kia Makarechi  | 2012-01-28  |
| 1        | https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/black-smoker-vents-new-species_us_5bb10820e4b09bbe9a596463 | 'Black Smoker' Vents: New Species Discovered Near Deepest Undersea Hot Springs (PHOTOS) | ENVIRONMENT     | Photos and captions courtesy of University of Southampton and NOC. Connelly's co-leader, marine biologist Dr. Jon Copley |                | 2012-01-28  |
+----------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------+-------------+



But when using Spark to read from hive table, all rows are just copies of headers (I have dropped id and date columns):


+----+--------+--------+-----------------+-------+
|link|headline|category|short_description|authors|
+----+--------+--------+-----------------+-------+
|link|headline|category|short_description|authors|
|link|headline|category|short_description|authors|
|link|headline|category|short_description|authors|
|link|headline|category|short_description|authors|
|link|headline|category|short_description|authors|
+----+--------+--------+-----------------+-------+



This is my Spark code:


spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("spark://spark-master:7077") \
    .appName("Read Hive Table 2") \
    .config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://namenode:9000/user/hive/warehouse") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()
    
schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", LongType(), True),
    StructField("link", StringType(), True),
    StructField("headline", StringType(), True),
    StructField("category", StringType(), True),
    StructField("short_description", StringType(), True),
    StructField("authors", StringType(), True),
    StructField("date", DateType(), True) 
])

# Define the JDBC URL for HiveServer2
jdbc_url = "jdbc:hive2://hiveserver2:10000/vulm4_db"
username = "hive"       # Replace with your username
password = "password"      # Replace with your password

# Load the Hive table data
df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbc_url) \
    .option("dbtable", "news") \
    .option("user", username) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .option("header", "false") \
    .option("encoding", "UTF-8") \
    .option("multiline", "true") \
    .option("nullValue", "NA") \
    .load()
    
df2.drop("id").drop("date").show(5)



BTW, I'm using news category dataset at Kaggle
